# making sure random numbers are not the same using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following which will return 100k rows in the database which should find me 6 random values. The problem is in the Lotto you cannot have multiple same values. I have noticed that some values are showing up the same, eg..

`21-21-34-3-14-46`

Its clear that `21` and `21` are NOT valid numbers in a Lotto ticket. So my question is how do i check that no numbers are the same when generating a random value?

Here is my code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=500000)
BEGIN

--Do Stuff


DECLARE @Random1 INT, @Random2 INT, @Random3 INT, @Random4 INT, @Random5 INT, @Random6 INT, @Upper INT, @Lower INT
---- This will create a random number between 1 and 49
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 49 ---- The highest random number
SELECT @Random1 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random2 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random3 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random4 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random5 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random6 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
--SELECT @Random;

INSERT INTO CustomerSelections
           ([draw_date]
           ,[val1]
           ,[val2]
           ,[val3]
           ,[val4]
           ,[val5]
           ,[val6])
     VALUES
           (
           '2013-07-05'
           ,@Random1
           ,@Random2
           ,@Random3
           ,@Random4
           ,@Random5
           ,@Random6 
           )


SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

**@Gordon:**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I think of random numbers with no duplicates, I think "permutation".  So, the idea is to generate the set of possible values, order them randomly, and then choose the first six values as your set:

```
with nums as (
    select @lower as n
    union all
    select nums.n+1
    from nums
    where nums.n < @upper
   ),
   randnums as 
   (select nums.n, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
    from nums
   )
select @random1 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 1 then rn.n end),
       @random2 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 2 then rn.n end),
       @random3 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 3 then rn.n end),
       @random4 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 4 then rn.n end),
       @random5 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 5 then rn.n end),
       @random6 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 6 then rn.n end)
from randnums rn;
```

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff: this is very good however its not very random. It solves my problem where the same number does not come up multiple times but the randomness just isnt there.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton . . . I really don't know what you mean.  When I test this code, it produces very different combinations each time.  The randomness should be guaranteed by the `order by newid()`.  Here is a SQLFiddle that has the same logic (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16696) -- all the variables are hardcoded because I haven't figured out how to get SQLFiddle to handle variables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: If i run your code 10,000 times and then run the query you gave in my other question to show the count for how many times the different numbers came up, you'll know what i mean.. I would expect some numbers to come up MORE and LESS often. The frequency just doesnt seem right, its too close. Please see uploaded screenshot in my question above.. thanks

Comment: So the question of the decade is, "how random is random?" I see you wrote a book. I might go buy it, i am interested in data mining, just trying to create my own Lotto data sets hence need to work out if im creating it right. Would be greatful if you could point me to any fundraising datasets (free?) so i can predict potential donations to a charity.. :)

Comment: @PriceCheaperton . . . Do you have much of background in statistics?  When running a process like this 10,000 times, you would expect the values to appear equally often, with the actual counts centered on the actual value and a standard deviation (or variance) that is closely approximated by a function of the number of samples.  I haven't analyzed those particular numbers, but they suggest randomness to me.  You should study up on probability, combinatorics, and the Poisson distribution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Im a nOOb former web developer, just looking into stats / data mining on the weekends for a hobby. Thanks for your help. Any ideas on datasets?

Comment: @PriceCheaperton . . . My book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel" has sample data sets with examples using them throughout the book.